# moving selected data two tabs

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file with one column and it looks like this.

```
chr1
C1orf122
YRDC
chr1
chr1
chr1
chr1
NADK
chr1
chr1
```

I want to move the data 2 tabs in the first column if it does not start with chr.

expected output

```
    chr1
                      C1orf122
                      YRDC
    chr1
    chr1
    chr1
    chr1
                      NADK
    chr1
    chr1
```

I am doing this

```
awk '{if($1 ~ /chr*/) print $_ ; else print "\t\t" $1}' <result >temp
```

The data doesn't move 2 tabs :(

Please help

Thank you

Comment: could you give us an example of the expected output??

Comment: I have made the edit, please check it

Comment: it is working for me (I am getting the expected output)

Comment: does this mean my file has some hidden characters which are not making it work?

Comment: If yes, then how can I see them and how I can get rid of them

Comment: I am using gawk instead of awk. Maybe it is not the same in this case.

Comment: I have no clue what is happening in my file.

Comment: you can try to create a new file from the input that you described above (C&P I did it, and it worked)

Comment: Is there a way to see the hidden characters causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed '/^chr/!s/.*/\t\t&/' file.txt
```

Results:

```
chr1
        C1orf122
        YRDC
chr1
chr1
chr1
chr1
        NADK
chr1
chr1
```

(There's actually two tabs there). If you add the `-i` flag, you can make the changes *in_place* and avoid the need to use a temp file.

Comment: Something is wrong with my Input file. I am unable to figure out what .... Iguess it has some hiddeen characters or something

Comment: @Angelo: What's the result of `sed -n l0 file.txt`? This will show you the hidden chars. Otherwise, perhaps try `dos2unix`.

Comment: this is the result chr22\t41869347\t41869847\tMCAT$
\t\t\tMCAT$
the original file has 4 columns. Hence you see 4 columns here as well

Comment: @Angelo: So both your code and my code works on my machine at least. What shell are you using? What is your tabwidth set to? Try typing `tabs -8` to reset your tabwidth to default size. Failing that, try re-creating the problem using spaces instead of tabs. What are the results?

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of comments to your program, which works here btw (GNU awk):

- `$1 ~ /chr*/` tries to find `ch` or `chr` or `chrr` etc. in the first field. If you meant `chr` followed by anything use `chr.*` and if it should be anchored at the beginning of the field use `/^chr.*/`.
- `$_` is a perl variable, I think awk assumes you meant `$0`, i.e. the whole line (record).

Usually if your code block starts with an `if` you could make it into the conditional for that block, e.g. start with:

```
$1 ~ /^chr.*/ { ... }
```

In your case you want to prepend the line with `\t\t` if it doesn't start with `chr`, I would express it like this:

```
$1 !~ /^chr.*/ { printf("\t\t") } 1
```

The `1` at the end prints `$0`.

Output:

```
chr1
        C1orf122
        YRDC
chr1
chr1
chr1
chr1
        NADK
chr1
chr1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk '{$2=$1; sub($(!/chr1/),"",$1); sub($(/chr1/),"",$2); print $1 "\t\t" $2 }' file
```

Result:

```
awk '{$2=$1; sub($(!/chr1/),"",$1); sub($(/chr1/),"",$2); print $1 "\t\t" $2 }' file
chr1        
        C1orf122
        YRDC
chr1        
chr1        
chr1        
chr1        
        NADK
chr1        
chr1
```